# How can i implement grid layout as follows?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I want to implement gridlayout like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYGP.jpg
I have already implemented almost all the stuff but i am unable to align grid item as in given url. How can set grid item slightly above in second column. Is it possible to do the same? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking for a StaggerdGrid look at [this](http://codeascraft.com/2014/01/13/android-staggered-grid/) link

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look at following demos on git hub for staggered grid view that you are taking about.

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Thanx.You can ask if you have any further queries :) Happy coding.